# showing entire instance variable in rails views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, partial-views

Suppose I get all the users by `@users = User.all`, then in my partial I have some loop

```
%ul
        = users.each do |index|
          = content_tag(:li,index.name)
```

the problem, is that I get this output

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Administrator //correct user name 
    <li>
    [#&lt;User id: 1, email: "admin@local.host", encrypted_password: "$2a...",...;]
</ul>
```

Why is the entire object displayed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use this

```
    %ul
      - users.each do |user|
        =content_tag(:li, user.name)
```

the difference between `-` and `=` is that the first wont output but the second will. As so,`- = users.each do |user|` rendered the entire instance variable (precisely passed as a local)

Comment: @MrYoshiji sorry, copy pasting issue ;)

Comment: @MrYoshiji sorry I wanted to edit mine and I put something within. So sorry !

Comment: It's okay if you didn't do it on purpose ;)

Answer (score 0):

Because of `=` sign in the beginning of the line. It should be:

```
%ul
  -users.each do |user|
    =content_tag(:li, user.name)
```

I used `user` as an instance variable name passed to the block, for better readability.

Comment: yes but I passed `@users` as a local `user` in my partial. So how can I manage this ?

Comment: @user1611830 You should pass it as `users`. Look my answer again.

Comment: no then I get an error method telling me each is not recognized as a method